# How to build a crate to a different target with the cargo crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am using the cargo crate to build a rust project using the `cargo::ops::compile()` function. I also have a custom target in a json file.

How do I use that target file to build the project to the correct target? Is there a place for a target in the `CompileOptions` struct? I know that there is `rustc_target_args` in that struct, do I have to manually convert my target to a list of rustc arguments?